# Haskell-mode not working for my project, can't find module

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

Here is my scenario:

I'm working on a project with the following directories/modules:

```
|--proj
   |-- src
       |-- Foo
           |-- FooModule1.hs
           |-- FooModule2.hs
       |-- Bar
           |-- BarModule1.hs
```

`BarModule1.hs` looks like this:

```
module BarModule1 where

import Foo.FooModule1
...
```

I also have a `.cabal` file specifying `src` as the `hs-source-dirs` and of course both modules are listed in it.

When I am in the file `BarModule1.hs` in Emacs and I do <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> it says:

```
proj/src/Bar/BarModule1.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module `Foo.FooModule1'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Also I want to use `hlint` with `flymake-haskell-multi-load` and if I activate that mode with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flymake-haskell-multi-load`, `hlint` will always show the error that it can't find module `Foo.FooModule1`, because it is not aware of the `.cabal` file, in which I specify that `hs-source-dirs: src`.

***So my question is:*** How can I make `haskell-mode` and `flymake`/`hlint` be aware of my project directory/module tree, so that it finds all modules?

Alternatively, how can I make them aware of the modules specified in my `.cabal` file?

Comment: If you are using a cabal file, then why not use cabal itself? First make sure your current buffer is a file in the same folder as your .cabal file, then `C-u M-x compile RET cabal repl RET`

Comment: What version of haskell-mode are you using? The latest and greatest is very cabal aware. Same for ghc-mode IIRC

Comment: C-u M-x compile RET cabal repl RET works for the repl but does not fix the flymake/hlint issue



I am using haskell-mode 13.7

Answer (score 4):

As for `haskell-mode` set `haskell-process-type` to `cabal-repl` in your emacs init file and make sure to use `interactive-haskell-mode` (not `inf-haskell-mode`):

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)
(setq haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl)
```

Answer (score 3):

My emacs configuration is based on [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). And I also create sandbox for the project with `cabal sandbox init`.

For the similar project structure `haskell-mode` works well. I am able to <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> load current file into repl without errors. But `flycheck` is unable to resolve all modules and highlight `import` statements with errors:

```
Could not find module ‘Foo.FooModule1’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

There is an issue [Support Cabal sandboxes in GHC #293](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/293) with the solution. You need to create `.dir-locals.el` in the `proj` root which provides necessary variables.

```
((haskell-mode
  (flycheck-ghc-package-databases "/path/to/proj/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d/")
  (flycheck-ghc-no-user-package-database . t)
  (flycheck-ghc-search-path "/path/to/proj/src")))
```

- `flycheck-ghc-package-databases` - is a `cabal.sandbox.config` (you may need to create sandbox first) `package-db` setting
- `flycheck-ghc-search-path` - is a path to `proj/src`

Answer (score 2):

At the prompt in ghci: `:set -iproj/src/`

Comment: This fixes the C-c C-l problem, thanks.
But still, flymake with hlint will not be affected by it, and still marks the first import line with "Could not find Module"